# Confusing character encoding in R

Tags: r, character-encoding

I have two dataframes which I am unable to share fully due to the data being confidential. I am supposed to merge them using the LABEL variable which exists in both datasets and contains some Unicode characters such as č, ž and so forth. However, the merging process created more rows than expected and on further inspection, I have found out that in the first dataframe, the values that contain Unicode characters are transcribed literally (e.g. you can see the label `VŽ` in the dataframe), whereas in the second dataframe, the label is shown via its Unicode code, so instead of `VŽ` you would see `V\u008e`. I used the `stri_enc_mark` function on both dataframes, here is the code and output for dataframe 1:

```
stri_enc_mark(unique(data1$Label)) %>% cbind(unique(data1$Label))
```

Output:

```
      .           
 [1,] "ASCII" "ZD"
 [2,] "ASCII" "RI"
 [3,] "ASCII" "PU"
 [4,] "ASCII" "ZG"
 [5,] "ASCII" "DU"
 [6,] NA      NA  
 [7,] "ASCII" "KR"
 [8,] "ASCII" "DA"
 [9,] "ASCII" "MA"
[10,] "ASCII" "ST"
[11,] "UTF-8" "VŽ"
[12,] "ASCII" "KA"
[13,] "ASCII" "SB"
[14,] "ASCII" "BM"
[15,] "ASCII" "VT"
[16,] "ASCII" "BJ"
[17,] "ASCII" "DJ"
[18,] "ASCII" "OS"
[19,] "ASCII" "SK"
[20,] "ASCII" "GS"
[21,] "UTF-8" "PŽ"
[22,] "UTF-8" "ŠI"
[23,] "UTF-8" "KŽ"
[24,] "ASCII" "Vk"
[25,] "UTF-8" "ŽU"
[26,] "ASCII" "KC"
[27,] "ASCII" "DE"
[28,] "ASCII" "NA"
[29,] "UTF-8" "ČK"
[30,] "ASCII" "KT"
[31,] "ASCII" "IM"
[32,] "ASCII" "VU"
[33,] "ASCII" "NG"
[34,] "ASCII" "VK"
[35,] "ASCII" "OG"
[36,] "ASCII" "SL"
```

And for dataframe 2:

```
stri_enc_mark(unique(data2$Label)) %>% cbind(unique(data2$Label))
```

Output:

```
      .                
 [1,] "ASCII" "BJ"     
 [2,] "ASCII" "BM"     
 [3,] "UTF-8" "\xc8K"  
 [4,] "ASCII" "DA"     
 [5,] "ASCII" "DE"     
 [6,] "ASCII" "DJ"     
 [7,] "ASCII" "DU"     
 [8,] "ASCII" "GS"     
 [9,] "ASCII" "IM"     
[10,] "ASCII" "KA"     
[11,] "ASCII" "KC"     
[12,] "ASCII" "KR"     
[13,] "ASCII" "KT"     
[14,] "UTF-8" "K\u008e"
[15,] "ASCII" "MA"     
[16,] "ASCII" "NA"     
[17,] "ASCII" "NG"     
[18,] "ASCII" "OG"     
[19,] "ASCII" "OS"     
[20,] "ASCII" "PU"     
[21,] "UTF-8" "P\u008e"
[22,] "ASCII" "RI"     
[23,] "ASCII" "SB"     
[24,] "ASCII" "SK"     
[25,] "ASCII" "ST"     
[26,] "UTF-8" "\u008aI"
[27,] "ASCII" "VK"     
[28,] "ASCII" "VU"     
[29,] "UTF-8" "V\u008e"
[30,] "ASCII" "ZD"     
[31,] "ASCII" "ZG"     
[32,] "UTF-8" "\u008eU"
[33,] "ASCII" "VT"
```

So as far as I can see, both the "literal" labels and the labels with Unicode code are encoded as UTF-8, which I find surprising because if that is the case, **I cannot comprehend why is one dataframe showing *VŽ* and the other one *V\u008e***.

I want to convert the coded labels to literal labels, I have tried to the following:

```
data2 %>%
  mutate(Label = recode(Label, "\xc8K" = "ČK",
                             "K\u008e" = "KŽ",
                             "P\u008e" = "PŽ",
                             "\u008aI" = "ŠI",
                             "V\u008e" = "VŽ",
                             "\u008eU" = "ŽU"))
```

But this doesn't succeed and I get the following warnings:

```
Warning messages:
1: unable to translate 'K<U+008E>' to native encoding 
2: unable to translate 'P<U+008E>' to native encoding 
3: unable to translate '<U+008A>I' to native encoding 
4: unable to translate 'V<U+008E>' to native encoding 
5: unable to translate '<U+008E>U' to native encoding
```

So, how can I recode the values properly?

Comment: `\u008E` is _Single Shift Two_ while `Ž` (_Latin Capital Letter Z With Caron_) is  unicode `\u017D`; however, `Ž` is `\x8E` in _ACP 1252_ US & Western Eu, and _ACP 1250_ Central Europe.